# Enabling CORS in Kubernetes API server with HTTPS

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest, kubernetes

I'm trying to work with Kubernetes API server from Angular JS front-end app. The API server uses https endpoint. The front-end app is deployed to the other server.

Despite the `--cors-allowed-origins=.*` (or `--cors-allowed-origins=["http://*"]`) param for `kube-apiserver` I can't access API because when I try to make GET XHR request, pre-flight `OPTIONS` request failed with 401 response without CORS headers.

However, when I switch from https to http, everything works fine.

Looks like I'm facing [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/16431) issue, which is already fixed and merged in the version of Kubernetes I'm using.

Versions are Kubernetes 1.2.4, Angular JS 1.5.4 and Chrome 51.

Could you tell me why it happens and how to fix this? I need a working solution for https.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you linked to was fixed, but a regression in CORS handling was introduced by [kubernetes/kubernetes#18113](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/18113) and has yet to be fixed (see [kubernetes/kubernetes#24086](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24086)). It is currently marked as a known issue for the imminent 1.3 release, which means that it is an outstanding bug.

Comment: I tried to make it clear in my comment, but this *won't* be fixed in 1.3.0. Instead, it's marked as a known issue that this *doesn't* work in that release.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit kubernetes API server yaml file, to get CORS working.

Location: `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

Add `- --cors-allowed-origins=http://www.example.com,https://*.example.com` this line under `kube-apiserver`

```
spec:
containers:
- command:
  - kube-apiserver
  - --cors-allowed-origins=http://www.example.com,https://*.example.com
```

Coma separated domains or regular expressions you can add.

No need to restart `kube-apiserver`, once file saved `kube-apiserver` will automatically restart.

it will take 5 to 10min time to get API server up.